# email mailbox username compromised

Tags: email

I host my own email server courtesy of Synology MailPlus Server. In an effort to increase security I created a username consisting of 25 random characters. I monitor the mail logs of this server daily and to my surprise I can see a small number of logins from various IP addresses failing to authenticate using this username.
I have configured the mailbox for IMAP using SSL/TLS and prohibit plaintext authentication over unencrypted connection.
I'm at a loss how this username is becoming visible to others?

Comment: Do you by any chance use Outlook to access your mail via IMAP? Are these IP addresses from Microsoft? See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209163/outlook-for-android-uses-intermediate-microsoft-servers

Comment: By "username" do you mean the email address user name or the admin account username? If you mean the email address, that's considered public data and is fairly easy to discover.

Comment: I purposely did not use an email address as the username for this email account but instead chose a random 25 character username. This username is not the admin account username.

Comment: No I do not use Outlook to access my Mail server, my email client is Apple Mail and no the IP addresses do not belong to Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

The email address is visible:

1. to the recipients
2. in log files of SMTP servers transferring email from and to it.

Feel free to guess where the leak happened you **clearly** state the above options are excluded in your case.

Comment: I appreciate the email address will be visible to others but I did not use the email address as the username for this mailbox but generated a random 25 character username instead. My question is how someone got hold of this username?